# Object storage alternatives in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

so I am developing a Quiz plugin for Wordpress.

I have defined a shortcode which is replaced by my html, and I also have enqueued javascript and styles. So far all good.

At this point, I want to visualize each question using ajax and jquery. My quiz has some sophisticated logic - some quiz question-trees can fall off depending on the answers and on the settings of the plugin.

Thus, I am trying to achieve a solution, where javascript uses ajax call to fetch one next question at a time. On the backend, I created controller-class which is responsible for handling the logic and outputing the fetched-question's html code. Thus, whenever a starts the quiz, the backend will generate some controller object.

My question is, how can i store multiple controller objects persistently? So that i can get the current use's progress.

To do that, i need some kind of persistent storage for all the running quizzes. Here, as far as I understand, i have 2 alternatives: put serialized controller objects into the database, or use some sort of WP_CACHE.

So now I have some questions:

1) Is there any other alternative for storing a set of objects in Wordpress?

2) Is the approach I am using for the quiz implementation - okay? Like maybe I am doing something unconventional?

3) Is having ajax calls communicating to the DB a good idea?

*** Edit ***

Thanks to @cabrerahector, who pointed out the set_transient() wordpress API.

I was able to store an object in the db with the following code:

```
...
$base64_serial = base64_encode(serialize($report_controller));            
set_transient($report_id, $base64_serial, 60*60*12); 
...
```

and then retreive the object with the following code:

```
...
$report_controller = unserialize(base64_decode( get_transient( $_GET['report_id'] )));
...
```

I know it's kind of hacky, but does anybody know a better way? Please don't tell me to create an array with all fields of the class...

Comment: WordPress has its own caching API. Have a look at the Codex for more details.

Comment: I have read it, but it requires me to change the wp-config.php, and since I am developing a plugin, i do not want to do that... I guess i cannot enforce the WP_CACHE setting from the plugin, right ?

Comment: You don't need to touch the wp-config.php file at all. I was talking about this: [wp_cache_set()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_set/) (or [set_transient()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/)).

Comment: @cabrerahector somehow, when i do wp_cache_set() in ajax-action, then i cannot retreive the old object on the next ajax-action call...

Comment: @cabrerahector neither did `set_transient($id, "abc", 60*60*12);` work...

Comment: We can't help you unless you post some code. All we can do with what you have provided so far is guess.

Comment: @cabrerahector you are right :) done